# How to display image in uitableviewcell with subtitle style

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to use the .subtitle UITableViewCell style, but also be able to display an image in the cell. Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to subclass UITableViewCell? I want all the same labels and imageViews to have the same frame+sizing as the default classes.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide us with the piece of code you're trying to use until now?

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried already. UITableViewCell supports what you want without any extra work. Use the `imageView` to set the image. Use the `subtitle` style to get the two labels.